# How to paginate a nested form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, pagination

I have a form that has nested form with a lot of rows. How can I paginate it (I am using will_paginate) so that every page is saved at once during editing.

Thanks

Comment: have you considered using a wizard? [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked?autoplay=true)  railscasts can help you if you'd consider taking a diff approach.